# Changes to NSFileWrapper contents visible from terminal but don't show up in Finder

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsfilewrapper

I recently converted my OS X app to use a package-based file format instead of a single-file one. My document class is a sub-class of NSDocument, and I'm using the -fileWrapperOfType: to generate the file wrapper for writing and letting the framework do the write to disk. (In other words, I'm not using any of the write methods from NSFileWrapper itself.)

I'm running 10.9.4, Xcode 5.1.1, 10.9 SDK.

I am able to read and write the file OK, and if I make changes to the document they do get properly written out to the file package. I can see the changes when I examine the file package contents from the terminal, and the changes are present as expected when I read the file back in.

However, the changes do not appear in the Finder when I examine the package contents using the "Show Package Contents" command.

Do I need to do something to get the Finder to recognize the changes to the package contents?

Thank you for any advice or ideas on this one!